# Cannot upgrade simple shell to fully interactive session

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, ctf

I am learning CTF and have problems with upgrading shell.

This is instruction I use - https://blog.ropnop.com/upgrading-simple-shells-to-fully-interactive-ttys/#method-3-upgrading-from-netcat-with-magic

Method 1 does not help - Ctrl+C stopes netcat.

Method 2 does not work - after set up a listener, terminal stop respond to any keys.

Method 3 almost work - but after pressing Enter I get ^M on terminal and commands do not run.

What I am doing wrong? How can I upgrade the shell?

Comment: Since this is about a CTF, try asking this question over at https://security.stackexchange.com/ as they might have more knowledge about this topic.

Comment: ...if you aren't writing a program for the purpose, it's not on topic on Stack Overflow. (And questions need to be self-contained to be on-topic here; links are fine, but a question has to be answerable, and the answer needs to be understandable for others to learn from, even after links break).